# Ruby Mocha Unittest can't find "has_key" method

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, ruby-mocha

I've written a Unit test using *Test::Unit* and *Mocha*. I'm using "expects" to mock a method in a class I'm testing, and I want to check if a certain parameter is passed into the object:

```
service.expects(:get).once.with(path, has_key('t')).returns([])
```

On my development system, this runs just fine. On my colleague's computer, as well as on the Travis CI servers, the unit test fails with the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `has_key' for #<FloxTest:0x000000036d4770>
```

The same happens with all other methods that Mocha is supposed to add to the unit test, e.g. the "mock()" method.

I know that Mocha is picky concerning the import order. I imported it after "test/unit", though:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'mocha/test_unit'
```

If anyone needs more context, the complete test file is [here](https://github.com/Gamua/Flox-Ruby/blob/master/test/test_flox.rb#L47). In fact, the complete project is open source, and it's a rather small project: [GitHub](https://github.com/Gamua/Flox-Ruby);
the complete error log can be seen on [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/Gamua/Flox-Ruby).

I don't have any more ideas on what I could try. We even made sure that my colleague has the exact same gem versions as I have; and the Ruby version is also identical.

Thanks in advance for any help from a Ruby Guru out there, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now added this as [an issue on the Mocha issue tracker](https://github.com/freerange/mocha/issues/193) on your behalf.

You can see my suggested fix in [my comment there](https://github.com/freerange/mocha/issues/193#issuecomment-36508036). I hope that helps.

Comment: Indeed, that worked perfectly fine, thanks a lot! 
For reference / other readers: I've exchanged 'mocha/test_unit' with 'mocha/setup'. The reason for the problem was that the standard library version of 'Test::Unit' uses 'MiniTest' internally, so it's 'MiniTest' that needs to be manipulated by Mocha.

Comment: @JamesMead why don't you include the fix in your answer here, since link-only answers are of limited use (and for that reason, are generally considered non-answers on stack overflow).